# is there a web app for remote presentation?

Tags: sharing, pdf, slideshare

I have a PDF slideshow (not Microsoft PowerPoint), and I want to present the slideshow to someone remotely. I can use Skype for the voice, but I want to also be able to have the slides he sees synchronized with what I see without me having to let him know which slide I am on (so when I click, he goes to the next slide as well).

Is that possible through some web service (you upload the PDF and then it is synchronized when other people access the same page)?

Comment: Questions seeking application recommendations are now considered off-topic for this site. See the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is [Slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't personally used them, but [dpcloud](http://dpcloud.co/) looks like it might do what you want. You could also look into the possibility of using a livecasting service like [Vokle](http://www.vokle.com/)/[uStream](http://www.ustream.tv/)/[Justin.tv](http://www.justin.tv/)/[LiveStream](http://livestream.com/) with a screen-recording tool. (Both approaches would just transmit a live recording of you navigating the presentation yourself. Vokle also has a system for taking audience questions.)

Another option would be to use [Simple HTML Slides](http://richard.milewski.org/shs). It's not a hosted offering, but all it needs for running the sync server is the smallest, cheapest web host you can find that offers PHP and Memcached (eg. a [few-dollar VPS](http://www.lowendbox.com/), your own PC with a [DynDNS Free](http://dyn.com/dns/dyndns-free/) account to hook up a domain name, etc.). Synchronized remote presentations is the whole reason it was written.

It also has instructions for [converting from PDF](http://slides.netfools.com/downloads/PDFslides.html) (though, if you don't have iPhoto, you'll need to look up another way to go from PDF to a set of JPEG/PNG images) and the author recently took a blog post about what a web-based Powerpoint/Keynote killer [must do](http://www.wait-till-i.com/2010/11/02/why-i-dont-write-my-slides-in-html/) and converted it into a [scorecard/checklist](http://richard.milewski.org/shs/slide-scorecard) for Simple HTML Slides.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a multipage PDF, you can remote-control your show to your audience with 
[SIMPLYSLIDES](http://www.simplyslides.com). It's a free web app that's exactly designed to do that.